# Google Books API find exact author

Tags: google-books, google-books-api

Working with the Google Books API, I'd like to be able to display other books by the same author, but the only 'author'-related filter I'm seeing in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using) is `inauthor`, which is looking for any authors that match the text provided:

`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=inauthor:Richard+Moreno&key=my_key`

Returns several books by authors with the first name 'Richard', not specifically 'Richard Moreno'

Is there a parameter I can specify that I want only books by the exact same author?

Or do I need to filter the results myself to try to find an exact match?

Answer (score 3):

After finding the author on Google Books and clicking his name, Google put together this search:

`https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=inauthor:"Richard+Moreno"`

Which clued me in to using quotes to find an exact match. I should have known this was possible, but the aforementioned docs leave that out.

So now my query is:

`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=inauthor:"Richard+Moreno"&key=my_key`

Which works as I wanted